# Is there a way to use MFC's CEdit's function "ShowBalloonTip" without compiling with /UNICODE?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

we have a 1 million+ lines MFC sofware compiled with MBCS character set, and we would want to take advantage of CEdit's ShowBalloonTip or other "Vista common control"'s features. However in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531404), it states that in order to use theses functions, program should be compiled with /UNICODE

Is there a way to use these functions without enabling /UNICODE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can send the EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP message yourself, you don't have to use the CEdit helper method.  But of course you cannot avoid having to provide Unicode strings to initialize the required EDITBALLOONTIP structure.  Plenty of conversion methods around, mbtowc() or MultiByteToWideChar() get the job done.

Comment: Excellent answer! I tried almost everything but this! You made my day!